# InfoPath: How to display multiple fields for a lookup column

Tags: infopath

Looking at the configuration I dont see a way to display multiple columns. is it possible? If not, can you suggest another method where I will user an option to link current item to an existing list item.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://amanda.brainspire.com/2013/09/how-to-pull-in-sharepoint-lookup.html) is a very nice link explaining in detail regarding the requirement in questions.
Following are main steps:

1) Add new receive data connection.

2) Select List from which you want to fetch data.

3) Select all additional fields you want to be displayed on form.

4) Insert a calculated column on form.

5)Click on Advanced View for this field.

6) Select new data connection from dropdown.

7) Expand dataFields.

8) Select field you want to bring into form, do NOT click OK.

9) Click 'Filter Data…' at bottom of window.

10) Add…

11) Select the lookup ID from the Source List in the first dropdown - in my case "ID"

12) Click 'Select a field or group…' from the dropdown on the right.

13) Select the 'Main' data source from the top dropdown.

14) Select the lookup ID as it is named in the Target List ('Main')

15) Cick OK for all dialog boxes

Refer to link for detailed explanation with screenshots.

Comment: Hi 404. Thanks for your reply. I will go ahead and test your proposal. meanwhile marking as complete. Thanks

Comment: It works fine, is there any way to store the calculated field so it won't become refresh whenever I open the form, (I have a project report form which the overall progress is set on the project form, I want to display the overall progress on the report form in the time the report is created, and after updating the progress in the project form I don't want to be updated in report form)